# How to create a program which counts the frequency of an integer in a list or dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, counter, frequency

I am writing a program in python that prompts the user to enter a number of integer values. The program will need to store the integers, counts the frequency of each integer and display the frequency. (The number of elements to stored could be anything...5, 6, 7)
I tried to start with 2 for nested loops first one just to add the numbers in the list but I do know hot to implement the counter

The output should be something like this print( Integer value, "occurs", frequency, "times)

```
input_list = int(input("Input the number of elements to be stored in a list: "))

list = []

 for x in range(input_list):
    list.append(input("Element - 0: "))
    list.append(input("Element - 1: "))
    list.append(input("Element - 2: "))
    list.append(input("Element - 3: "))
    list.append(input("Element - 4: "))
    print("The frequency of all elements of the list:\n")
         for y in counter(list)
         counter = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
input_len = int(input())
counts = []
for i in range(input_len):
    numbers = map(int, input().split())
    for number in numbers:
        counts.append(number)

# Get frequencies
for count in set(counts):
    print('frequency of', count, 'is', counts.count(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Hope this would help.

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,56]
data_dict = {}
for num in data:
  try:
    data_dict[num] += 1
  except:
    data_dict[num] = 1

print(data_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but user will input the integers so I have to use the integers which user wanted

Comment: Sure bro @SergioIzcueFreire, we can also do that. You just have convert the input of the user in above format.

Comment: @SergioIzcueFreire whatever be the usecase that you may have. First thing would be to collect input from the user and store it somewhere. Only then you can do processing on it. So store it above format and process it.

Comment: If this has helped you any manner, please upvote and accept my answer. Thanks :)